# Typescript: How would I convert PropTypes.oneOf(Object.value(FOOBAR)) to a type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this that I want to convert to typescript

```
Tooltip.propTypes = {
  placement: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS)),
};
```

where TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS is defined in another file like this:

```
export const TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS = Object.freeze({
  TOP: 'top',
  BOTTOM: 'bottom',
  LEFT: 'left',
  RIGHT: 'right',
});
```

How would I do this in Typescript?

```
type Props = {
  placement: ???
}
```

I do not want to use the raw string literals. I need it to stay in that constant as an object

Comment: Does this question depend on react? If so you probably want to tag it as such. If not, you might want to remove references to `PropTypes` and replace them with something that doesn't require an external library to reproduce.

Comment: updated with react

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the prop type at all here. I think you just want:

```
export const TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS = Object.freeze({
  TOP: 'top',
  BOTTOM: 'bottom',
  LEFT: 'left',
  RIGHT: 'right',
} as const); // note: as const

type Props = {
    placement: (typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS)[keyof typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS]
}
```

You need the `as const` to force typescript to infer you strings as string literals and not just type `string`.

Then because `TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS` is a value, you need to get the `typeof` that value to make a type from it.

Lastly, you index that type by its own keys to get a union of its values.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=16&ssc=16&pln=16&pc=76#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBABShMAVAnmApgZzgM2RDgHIxkwBaGTXEgbgChGsAPSWOAYwgDsd4qAPJCAMqgCSCAPoJRAQQDCAUQCyygHKoAynAC8cIQCMAVli4wAdISxYAXlgAUAb0Zw4whAC5SMFCQAaNzgAISFUYVUfEiMIGD8QQODRZQAxVGiAGyx8GCT3ACUJAHEACQzSKGAAcwALPKCAXzgAQzwefhgASiZGfABXXgtgPg8ICEyYYDBHLrhnRsZUccnpy3IUDGw8A1d3MEyWriwQLF4YHyRN2hxLPiwhfEdjMwtLADcWzP7cR2ExSQyORKNSaHRdLpNXo0bCICg7ebBfaHY6nc4+RwwrAQfAeETiKSyBQqdRabRdADaAGssOgcXAsfT-gSgcTQWSALqMRaMAD0vIZuBgjA6AjgGzAOGK4wAJpd4fp5uKUSczhdfP44ItRfAJTgQi05XCUAjnMqjqr0aQ2jKSFq4Py4FgoMgoE72OYYFgZUA)

---

If really you do want to infer this from the `propTypes` it gets a little funkier.

You can make a utility type that will unwrap a specific prop type with something like:

```
type PropTypesRequireable<T extends PropTypes.Requireable<unknown>> =
    T extends PropTypes.Requireable<infer U> ? U : never

type Props = {
    placement: PropTypesRequireable<typeof Tooltip.propTypes['placement']>
}
```

This `PropTypesRequireable` type interrogate the generic parameter from the `PropTypes.Requirable<T>` type that `PropTypes.oneOf` returns, and pulls it out for you.

I'm not really sure that better, though. In fact I'm fairly sure it's not.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBABShMAVAnmApgZzgM2RDgHIxkwBaGTXEgbgChGsAPSWOAYwgDsd4qAPJCAMqgCSCAPoJRAQQDCAUQCyygHKoAynAC8cIQCMAVli4wAdISxYAXlgAUAb0Zw4whAC5SMFCQAaNzgAISFUYVUfEiMIGD8QQODRZQAxVGiAGyx8GCT3ACUJAHEACQzSKGAAcwALPKCAXzgAQzwefhgASiZGfABXXgtgPg8ICEyYYDBHLrhnRsZUccnpy3IUDGw8A1d3MEyWriwQLF4YHyRN2hxLPiwhfEdjMwtLADcWzP7cR2ExSQyORKNSaHRdLpNXo0bCIChbXAFLAAR36wCgWBaRmyAB5UHA2DAzgATPBXNA3SxI1HozHYrA4wYAa14EAA7rwAHyc-TBdz4wkksnwynUtEYrG44C8fBYKBwACqPIA-Iq4D5eFh3nLmDCsHCUDt5ny4AcjiczhcDRTtmLaZKGXqIPgxhMpmB1iLtgBtMiHY6nc4kAC6nMYi0YAHpI3AiQJGB0BKaKDhiuNiZcU-p5qb-RbztE-GASHBFon4BswDgQi0M9ajc5c+bA1aSG1iSXmtGCVBkPK2NgLFhiUA)

---

Or as @CRice points out, just use the `InferProps` provided by prop types.

```
type Props = InferProps<typeof Tooltip.propTypes>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=50#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBABShMAVAnmApgZwDRwDeAkgHYBmWUSKOAvnOciHAORjJgC0MmurAbgBQQrAA9IsOAGMIpHPFQB5JQBlUxBAH0EqgIIBhAKIBZIwDlUAZTgBeOEoBGAKyzSYAOiZYsALywAFIRCcHDKCABcbDAorHghcABCSqjKJlGsjhAwMSBxCapGAGKoGQA2WOQw+aEASsQA4gASpWxQwADmABbV8QwAhjgycgoAlMJC5ACupO7AcmEQEGUwwGABo0R0QqhLK2seHCgY2EP2waFgZf3SWCBYpDBRNGh8OB5yWErkAU6u7h4AG79MpTXABZRqDTaXSGUwWayjUZ9Ca8bCIThnOBkSjUTEAHjRWAg5EWy1WYEOnBOuAAfCIAPQMuAwXAwISyeTwI5gHANJYAE2emLsRDgVxudweT2isTg205CnFmMS-SFGNoosI4uut3ujwygwFrHlcCZcCoyCgFokblZAqAA)

Comment: Incidentally, the `prop-types` package exports a helper type `InferProps`, so there may not be a need to create a custom helper type to perform that inference.

Comment: Well, yeah, _apparently_ that's the real answer. :p

Comment: I'm trying to replace PropTypes with Typescript. Would I just do `placement: (typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS)[keyof typeof TOOLTIP_PLACEMENTS]` ?

Comment: If you're trying to get rid of proptypes entirely, then yeah, that's probably the right approach.